# Drawn rectangle isn't visible in Video Stream (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to make a simple program that draws a rectangle over a video stream coming from my webcam. The following code compiles and runs, but the rectangle isn't visible. I've tried various line thicknesses, colors, and positions; as well as tried to put rectangles simply on images rather than a video stream.

After looking through examples and tutorials as well as the OpenCV docs, I still can't seem to figure it out. If anyone could assist me in making the rectangle visible, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <opencv2/video.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

VideoCapture vid(0);
Mat frame;

int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        vid.read(frame);
        imshow("Webcam", frame);
        rectangle(frame, Point(100, 100), Point(300, 300), Scalar(255), 10, 8, 0);

        if (waitKey(30) == 27)
            break;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply draw the rectangle **before** you show the image:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp> // It's just easier to #include only this
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    // Don't use global variables if they are not needed!
    VideoCapture vid(0); 
    Mat frame;
    while(true)  
    {
        // Read frame
        vid.read(frame);

        // Draw rectangle
        rectangle(frame, Point(100, 100), Point(300, 300), Scalar(255, 0, 0) /*blue*/, 10, 8, 0);
        // Show image
        imshow("Webcam", frame);

        if ((waitKey(30) & 0xFF) == 27) { // for portability
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I was thinking the rectangle was treated as a separate entity to overlap the image, hence why I put it after I showed the image. Nonetheless, thank you for your help!